# Cannot read files in my project after publish WPF desktop app

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have a WPF desktop application. When I am in debug mode, I am able to access file.sql and read the contents.When I publish the file using visual studio and try to run the click once application,I am unable to read the file.sql file and the app cannot find the path. The .cs file where I am calling to read file.sql is located in the same folder.

```
string path = System.IO.Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory,@"..\..\ControlFolder","file.sql");
string readQuery = File.ReadAllText(path);
```

How can I ensure that I am able to read file.sql after publishing my app?

Comment: The code you posted has a syntax error.

Comment: Are you getting any error messages?

Comment: I fixed the syntax error, it was a copying error. @RobertHarvey I get error because it cannot find the file that I am trying to read. I am not sure how to find the appropriate path after its published. No errors before I publish.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you publish, you need to ensure that you are also publishing your "file.sql" to the binary output path.  The best practice is to avoid using relative paths to your source code, and instead you should always make sure that you point to files that you (the developer) will ensure exists in the published area.

Here's what I would do:

1. In Visual Studio, go to the properties of "file.sql" and make sure it is set to "Content" and "Copy if newer".  This will make sure that your "file.sql" will always exist in the binary output path.  If in Visual Studio, you have placed "file.sql" inside of a folder called "ControlFolder", then that means your binary output contents will contain a  ".\ControlFolder\file.sql" file.
2. Fix your code to never point to the relative path of your source code.  Instead, rely on the binary output path.  So instead of the code that you shared, replace it with this:

```
string path = System.IO.Path.Combine(System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location), @"ControlFolder\file.sql");
string readQuery = File.ReadAllText(path);
```